# Show results of a POST to the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I'm using node.js/express, and I've got a view with a form on it - that form POST's to a route, which then returns json.

I'd like to (to start with at least) send off my form, and have the data that's returned be shown underneath the form (on the same view).

What's the best way of doing this in the most 'express-y' way possible?

Ideally without a page refresh.

Ajax will do what I'm after - but is that a great way of doing it?

Thanks for any insight

Comment: You need a client-side language in order to update content on the page without a refresh, and considering you're also able to retrieve the data with AJAX, it seems perfect to me (assuming you're POSTing the data via AJAX).

Comment: Ajax will do it, and ajax is the only way to do it on the same page without refresh (or you can use socket, but not really the best way to handle just a form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bare minimum of what you're looking for would look something like this:

**Client side**

```
fetch('your_endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
  }).then((response) => {
    // success
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    // add data to DOM
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // failed to send
  });
}
```

**Server side using Expressjs**

```
router.post('/your_endpoint', (req, res, next) => {
    // process request
    res.status(200).json({ "data": your_data });
});
```